# Making an object move towards another moving object

Tags: python

I am currently using pygame and I have made an enemy and a player. I want the enemy to be able to move **straight** toward the player. The best solution I could find was:

```
if playerX > enimeX:
    enimeX_change = 0.1
else:
    enimeX_change = -0.1
if playerY > enimeY:
    enimeY_change = 0.1
else:
    enimeY_change = -0.1
```

This does make the enemy go toward the player, though it goes until it has an even Y or X value, then goes straight, so it's a curvy path. I want it to be a straight line from the current position to the players' position. Can someone help? Note:I am fairly new to coding so please dumb it down for me ha-

Comment: Lookup linear interpolation between two points or commonly known as lerping. You can choose the step toward the destination in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

anyway you have the code you need but let me make it a function for you

```
def enmy_follow_player(playerX, playerY, enemy_list):
   """
  If you want multiple enemies to follow the player, you can use a loop like 
  this and check them all one by one.
   """
    for enemy in enemy_list:
        if playerX > enemy[0]:
            enemy[0]  -= 0.1
        else:
            enemy[0] += -0.1
        if playerY > enemy[1]:
            enemy[1] -= 0.1
        else:
            enemy[1] += 0.1

position_of_all_enemy =[[100,100],[100,100],[100,100]]#store all enemy position in a list
player_pos = [100,100]

while True:
    follow = enmy_follow_player(player_pos[0],player_pos[1],position_of_all_enemy ) #you need to call this function continuously in a loop
```